# Is that how they did it? (Solving integrals by substitution solution)

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals

In case you're wondering, this part is taken from the answer key of my textbook, and was in the midst of an integrating by substitution solution, hence the **u**, (I just didnt write the whole thing out)

$$\int\frac{u^2-u}{u+1}du = \int(u-2)+\frac{2}{1+u}du$$

So this is the part which I don't seem to grasp on; how does the left side of the equation turn into the right side? I seem to know how they did it, it looks to me they **trialed and error with the cross factorisation** $(u^2-u)$ and then $-2+2$ such that it factorise nicely with it being $(u+1)(u-2)$.

Was that how they did it? Or is there a much cleaner way of doing that?

Alternatively, if I dont follow their answer key, the only method I can think of is a double substitution where $v=u+1$. Are there other ways?

Comment: It was done by long division where $u+1$ is divided into $u^2-u$. It can also be done by synthetic division.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-division-long.html

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
u^2 - u &= u(u+1)-u-u \\
&= u(u+1) -2u \\
&= u(u+1) -2(u+1-1) \\
&= u(u+1) -2(u+1)+2 \\
&= (u-2)(u+1)+2
\end{align}

Now, divide both sides by $u+1$.